# Trying to access an instance of a class from within a different class

Tags: java

I am trying to access a function from a class from within a class it was not created in.

Basically I have class A which can do b.refresh();

b obviously contains that function known as refresh. I now want class C to access it.

So in my mind it would be something like c.b.refresh(); but this clearly doesn't work.

What would I need to do to make it work? Only one instance of B is allowed.

Main class:

```
B b = new b();
b.refresh();
C c = new C();
```

Inside C:

```
function() {
//want to access the same b from Main class.
}
```

Comment: I don't follow, please add some code (including the basics of the mentioned classes and relevant methods signatures)

Comment: You need to revisit the distinction between an *object* and a *class*.

Comment: Mayank's answer will work unless both classes need to invoke the method on the SAME INSTANCE of `b`. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes I want them to access the same instance of b

Comment: Pass `B` into `C`'s constructor

Comment: How do I accomplish that? is it like giorashc answer?

Comment: you may have another function in C which takes B's object reference as parameter func1(B b) and inside which you can do b.refresh()...i think that shoul be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to share the B instance so :

```
public class C {

   private B b;

   C(B b) {
      this.b = b;
   }

   public refresh() {
      b.refresh();
  }
}
```

now you can do :

```
B b = new B();
C c = new C(b);
c.refresh();
```

And the same you can do with the A class passing the same B instance as :

```
A a = new A(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

If class C wants t access a method from Class B simply

```
B b=new B();
b.refresh();
```

the class A does not come into picture

Comment: +1 Assuming the question did not involve the need for `C` to invoke the method on the same instance of `B` as is held by `A`.

Comment: The problem is class B is a gui. So this would not affect it as it creates a new B.

Comment: So you need to update your question to clarify that only one instance of `B` is allowed.